# Is older version of flex SDK really required?

Tags: apache-flex, sdk, compilation

I am configuring one already done project on my system which uses old flex sdk. following is my POM

```
    <FLEX_HOME>${build.flex3sdk.path}</FLEX_HOME>
    <flash.player.version>10</flash.player.version>
    <flex.sdk.version>4.1.0.16248</flex.sdk.version>
```

I have latest flex SDK the version for this flex is "Version 4.5.1 build 21328". I am getting compile time error.  Does a flex Mojo is dependent on the version of flex SDK ?
why even changing the above POM to following is not helping me resolve the error?

```
        <FLEX_HOME>${build.flex3sdk.path}</FLEX_HOME>
        <flash.player.version>10</flash.player.version>
        <flex.sdk.version>4.5.1.21328</flex.sdk.version>
```

**Where can I find old sdk Version 4.1.0.16248?** Kind of stuck .. PLz help

Comment: What is the compiler error you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

For downloading legacy versions, you can use the links provided in the below website:
http://joshblog.net/2014/download-legacy-adobe-flex-sdk-versions/

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Open Source includes Flex down to version 3.

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK

They do have Flex SDK version 4.1.0.X. If you unable to find the version you need, perhaps you could get someone to share it with you from the Adobe Flex SDK Forum:

http://forums.adobe.com/community/opensource/flexsdk

Comment: yes I am already on it...does it really required to get the same version of SDK... Can you please let me know what is the dependency involved here . Is it due to flex mojo plugins...

Answer (score 0):

Adobe still maintains a list of downloadable [archived Adobe AIR runtimes and SDKs for versions 1.5 through 3.5](http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html). When the SDK was made open source and Flex was moved from Adobe to the Apache foundation, the later version SDKs are now available on SourceForge at:

- http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Versions/

If you want to download Flex 4.1A (Build 4.1.0.16076A), that can be done at:

- http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Download%20Flex%204/

The version you are looking for (4.1.0.16248) doesn't seem to be there (nor elsewhere). You may just have to use what is available from them in that case. However, depending on what compiler error you are seeing, this may or may not be an issue with the Flex SDK.